# Python import causing syntax error

Tags: python

I'm an old-fashioned Pascal programmer, new to OOP and Python, so please bear with me...I've got a book on Python and I've searched here first (although lots of similar threads - not checked every one)...

I'm trying to write a program to include existing modules written by others in my company. According to my Python book, I should be able to import whole modules or just specific classes. The book says that when 'import' is used, it actually runs the specified code (not like the INHERIT I'm used to in Pascal).

I have this structure in the module, mod.py, I want to use:

```
from x.y.z import stuff

class c1(superclass):
    def func1(self):
        ....
    def func2(self, db):
        ....
        with self.db as handler:
            ....
```

and I've got a basic script, test.py, that does just this:

```
from mod import c1

print "Hello"
```

when I execute 'python test.py', I get the error message:

```
'with self.db as handler' - invalid syntax
```

I think I'm missing something fundamental here, so any help much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that your `self.db` doesn't implement the [context manager protocol](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), or does it?

Comment: Could also be that this is too old a Python to have that syntax -- Python 2.4 still lives in production some places. Which version is this?

Comment: Your error suggests that you are putting the with statement in quotes, is that correct? What version of Python are you using? You should also update the question with the entire contents of `mod.py`

Comment: @TimPietzcker That wouldn't cause a syntax error, and wouldn't (couldn't) be checked at import time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have modified the error message, but I assume it looks like

```
  File "mod.py", line 8
    with self.db as handler:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This means that your Python version is too old to know the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). Update to an implementation that supports python 2.6+.

In Python 2.5, you can also add a [`__future__` declaration](http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html) at the top of `mod.py`, like this:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

Comment: Yes, that is what my error looks like. Hmm, I've been given an environment to use and I have no control over installing versions - would seem strange to have been given something out-of-date but I'll look into it...many thanks...

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.5 the with statement is not available by default. But it is there! :-) Try adding

`from __future__ import with_statement`

to your mod.py or use Python 2.6+.

Comment: Newbie question - how do I tell what version I've got? (I'm on a Linux server)

Answer (score 0):

Given what that line looks like and the error being a syntax one, I'd look at the line before it and look for unmatched braces or quotes.